# Writing/Read Windows Registry - Windows Service

Tags: delphi, windows-services, registry

I develop a Windows Service that will run under SYSTEM user. So I want to make a installer to configure this service. The installer will create entries in the windows registry.

When the Windows Service starts it will to read these entries, generated by the installer.

This entries will point to a Config File, and where to store the log files of the service.
Which key Do I need to write/read to make this work? I am worried about permissions.

Is it in the CURRENT_USER key?

I develop the Windows Service in Delphi.

Thanks,

Comment: If you are developing a service, I think it is safe to use the LOCAL_MACHINE key. Your service will need administrator priviledges for installation anyway, so you can include the initial values for the registry with the installer.

Comment: @DD: no, do not store your service config in HKEY_CURRENT_USER.  Your service runs in the SYSTEM account, but users will run the installer in their own accounts instead, so HKEY_CURRENT_USER will map to different sections of the Registry.  You have to use HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, or do not use the Registry at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remy's comment is correct.

The `SYSTEM` account does not have their own `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` registry hive.

You should be storing configuration information in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, or in your own custom xml configuration file in your AppData directory.

**Side note:** i believe that attempts to use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` when no profile hive is loaded will get you `HKEY_USERS/.DEFAULT`; which isn't something you want to be using.